# Synchronisation for a Windows 8.1 App

Tags: windows-runtime

I'm writing an application that requires synchronisation. My current plan is as follows:

Use a background task with a time of 15 minutes.

When the task is run call a webservice using http client and download/upload the items that have changed.

My understanding is that I get 2 cpu seconds, but downloading is async so shouldn't count. Is there any reason for my to use the backgrounddownloader/backgrounduploader since I'm already on the background thread?

Ta

Ross

Comment: What are you downloading? The background classes were intended for large files generally speaking.

Comment: Small files (maybe up to 4mb)

Comment: That starts to be the sweet spot for the right size to use the BackgroundDownloader.

Comment: But what benefit does it offer? It certainly makes the sync code more complex?

Comment: Have you read the docs on the benefits?

Comment: Yes, it will continue downloading in the background when your app closes. But since I'm downloading via a backgroundtask I get this anyway. Thats why I'm asking is there any benefit to also using a backgrounddownloader

Comment: I feel like the benefits are well covered on MSDN, like here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh452979  It's far more capable than what you could conveniently write in a background task.